# Admin dashboard does not show WordPress network sites

Tags: multisite

How do I fix that the admin panel show the sites that are in the WordPress network?

[image: WordPress dashboard]

It does show here:

[image: sites]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On default you can't display all sites of the network on a site of network, like your first screenshot. This is the Dashboard of a site. The site is instance of the network and have no data, dependencies of the network.

The network admin have all information about the network, also the list of all sites of this network. But you can't also view all sites in the dashboard, you find it only in the 'Sites' menu item.

Last chance if you need it - create a plugin, custom code to display a list of all sites on other views.